# Flask login not persisting across requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login

I'm using React with Flask and flask-login.  I have a login route that successfully logs in the user in the front end. However, as soon as I navigate to a new page, which causes a new API call to be made, flask returns a 401. I don't see anything in Cookies or Session Storage in the Firefox web console.

```
@flask_app.route('/<api_version>/login', methods=['POST'])
def login(api_version):
    print(f'login', request.form )
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    response = None
    try:
        user = server.loginUser(username, password)
        flask_login.login_user(user, remember=True)
    except Exception as e:
        errMsg = f'Error Logging in user {username}'
        status = e.status if hasattr(e, 'status') else 500
        print(f'{errMsg}')
        traceback.print_exc()
        return Response(
            '{{"message": "{0}", "status": {1} }}'.format(
                errMsg, status), status=status, mimetype='application/json')

    resp_obj = json.dumps({"username": user.username, "role": user.role})
    resp = Response(resp_obj, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return resp

@flask_app.route("/<api_version>/simulation-runs", methods=['GET'])
@flask_login.login_required
def get_simulation_runs(api_version):
...
```

server.py

```
from models import account # DB

def loginUser(username, password):
    print(f'loginUser {username}')
    user_db = account.get_account(username)
    print(f'User returned from DB: {user_db}')
    errMsg = 'Invalid username or password.  Please try again.'
    if not len(user_db) or (not 'password' in user_db):
        e1 = Unauthorized(errMsg)
        e1.status = 401
        raise e1

    #if request.form['password'] == users[username]['password']:
    #if password == user['password']:
    if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user_db['password'], password): 
        user = User()
        user.id = username
        user.username = username
        user.role = user_db['role']
        print(f'loginUser returning {vars(user)} is_active: ${user.is_active} is_authenticated: ${user.is_authenticated}')
        return user
    else:
        e1 = Unauthorized(errMsg)
        e1.status = 401
        raise e1
```

User.py

```
class User(flask_login.UserMixin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not logging the user and creating a session on the server.

flask_login.login_user(user) needs to be there for the server to understand that a login has been successful.

you should also create a new session by adding session['logged_in'] = True

It is advisable to have a user class that is well defined as well